# 2015 Subaru WRX Check Engine Light

Tags: subaru, obd-ii, cel, wrx

The check engine light on my WRX just came on yesterday, along with a batch of other lights. I bought it new, follow the recommended maintenance schedule, and haven't had any other major issues.

Context: yesterday I went and filled up at a new gas station (I'm not very discerning where I fill up, but I always do 91+, this was a Shell). After a couple of errand stops, I went back to my car and it had a notably rougher idle than usual. After a few seconds, the check engine light came on, cruise control started flashing, hill holder and traction control lights came on too. I immediately pulled over and did a once over of the outside. All looked good so I restarted the car and only got the check engine light, rough idle was gone.

I babied my car back home, and then hooked up an OBDII scanner and go the following codes:

- P0300: Confirmed - Random/multiple cylinder(s) - misfire
- C1422, C1413, B1011, B1012, B1013, B1014, U1500, B14A1: Confirmed - Test failed since last DTC clear
- C2548: Pending, Confirmed - Test failed since last DTC clear

I have an appointment at the dealership tomorrow, but hoping one of y'all might have some tips / things to check before then to potentially save me trip.

Comment: The P0300 is often related to a fueling problem.